# Access Pytest Fixture Params In Test

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a possibility to access the `request.param` from the test function?

**Setup Fixture with params**

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[0,10,20,30])
def wallet(request):
    return Wallet(request.param)
```

**Test**

```
def test_init_balance(wallet):
    assert wallet.balance == 10
```

**EDIT:** Added a `collections.namedtuple` solution

**What I got working until now**

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[20,30,40])
def wallet(request):
    FixtureHelper = collections.namedtuple('fixtureHelper', ['wallet', 'request'])
    fh = FixtureHelper(Wallet(request.param), request)
    return fh
```

**Then accessing it in the test**

```
def test_spend_cash(wallet):
    wallet.wallet.spend_cash(wallet.request.param)
```

I would still appreciate a better solution!

Comment: I don't think so, fixtures just return, in this case, objects like your `Wallet` thing. I'd be happy to be proven wrong, but it seems unlikely to me :(

Comment: You can return `request.param` directly from your fixture, not sure what is the complexity of your requirement though.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers in this duplicate question: [In pytest, how can I access the parameters passed to a test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501761/in-pytest-how-can-i-access-the-parameters-passed-to-a-test)

You can access it with `request.node.callspec.params`:

```py
def test_init_balance(request, wallet):
    assert wallet.balance == request.node.callspec.params.get("wallet")
```

Or you can refactor the fixtures slightly:

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=[0, 10, 20, 30])
def balance(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture
def wallet(balance):
    return Wallet(balance)


def test_init_balance(wallet, balance):
    assert wallet.balance == balance
```